# MySQL query to retrieve stream of messages sent to and from two users

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am building a networking site and would like the users to be able to see their messages to and from each user in one stream. Ideally I would like to achieve this with a query rather than getting php involved.

My table at the moment is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Message` (
  `message_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `message_subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `message_read` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

(but I can overhaul if beneficial)

as you can see there is a 'sent from' and a 'sent to' column and I need to get the messages that have been sent from A-B as well as messages from B-A. Is it possible with a query?

Or do I have to merge arrays in php?

Comment: Please provide sample data and the expected result.

Comment: The short answer is `yes`, this is easy to do in SQL. `SELECT * FROM Message WHERE (message_from = 'A' OR message_from = 'B' ) AND (message_to = 'A'  OR message_to = 'B' )`. Other syntax variations are possible, but this is the essence of it. As @PM77-1 says, for a more explicit answer provide more details for us to work with.

Comment: @fixdreamer add `AND message_to != message_from` to the end of Turophile's response to prevent getting messages to self in those results.

Comment: Thank you Steven Moseley have taken your advice, thanks to both of you :)